# Is it possible to fill collection within a class using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Let say we have two classes:

```
A:
[Key]
public long Id {get;set;}
public string SomeValueFromAddressTable {get;set;}
public string SomeValueFromPersonTable {get;set;}
public string SomeValueFromOrderTable {get;set;}
public long BId {get;set;}

B:
[Key]
public long Id {get;set;}
public IQUerable<A> AList {get;set;}
```

that represent the Dbo objects that take some of the data from database table (they are NOT exact database entity representation) - is it possible to fill the AList variable within Linq statement? I tried using few techniques but I can't seem to achieve what I want.

EDIT:

OK, allow me to explain a bit more:

I have standard database where - for example - User table has foreign keys to Address and some other tables. I want to get only some data from these tables in form of DTO (User.Id, User.Name, User.Address.City, User.Address.Street for example), User can have many addresses (One to many relation). I have created two DTO classes:

```
UserDto:

[Key]
public long Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}

public IQuerable<AddressDTO> AddressList {get;set;}

AddressDTO:

[Key]
public long Id {get;set;}
public string City {get;set;}
public string Street {get;set;}
```

I have tried something like this:

```
var userQuery = 
from user in Context.Users
join address in Context.Address on user.Id equals address .UserId
where address.IsActive=true
select new UserDto
{
Id = user.Id,
Name = user.Name,
AddressList = (from c in address select new AddressDTO
{
Id = c.Id,
City  = c.City,
Street = c.Street
}).AsQuerable()
}
```

But it won't compile - if I change the line:

```
from c in address select new AddressDTO
```

to the following

```
from c in user.Addresses select new AddressDTO
```

then it will compile but I don't think it will take the "where" condition into account. So the question is - is it possible to fill my such somehow? I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Have you tried a constructor?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean.  What did you try and how did it not work?

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and explain why it does not do what you want. Currently it is not clear why you can do `obj.AList = new Queue(some LINQ expression)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group in this situation like:

```
var userQuery = (
                from user in Context.Users
                join address in Context.Address on user.Id equals address.UserId
                where address.IsActive = true
                select new { userId = user.Id, userName = user.Name, addressId = address.Id, address.City, address.Street } into tmp
                group tmp by new { tmp.userId, tmp.userName, adresses = grouped.ToList() } into grouped
                select new UserDto
                {
                    Id = grouped.Key.userId,
                    Name = grouped.Key.userName,
                    AddressList = grouped.Select(c => new AddressDTO
                    {
                        Id = c.addressId,
                        City = c.City,
                        Street = c.Street
                    })
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, this seem to work (with minor modifications)... however the generated SQL is  much too complex - it would seem Linq can't optimize such query very well... :(

Comment: Yee linq generates complex queries even for simple things. That's true :)

Comment: I actually, managed to optimize quite a few Linq queries lately (I got the job to speed up a synchronization process - managed to get it from 45 minutes per device to 5-6 minutes), but "group into" seem to make this very hard if not impossible - I will try again though...